# Javascript function for searching a table from dropdown list options

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question table with a mix of 'easy' 'medium' and 'hard'. I want the user to be able to search by difficulty and topic from what they select from a drop down list. This is my code for the dropdown searches:

```
<div class="search">

  <label for="dflag"> Difficulty: </label>
  <select id="dflag" name="dflag">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="0">Easy</option>
      <option value="1">Medium</option>
      <option value="2">Hard</option>

      </select>
</div>
<div class="search">
  <label for="tflag"> Topic: </label>
  <select id="tflag" name="tflag">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="A">Arrays</option>
        <option value="S">Strings</option>
        <option value="C">Conditionals</option>
        <option value="L">Loops</option>
       </select>
</div>`<button type="submit" onclick="select()"> Submit </button>`
```

The code for my question table:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
      <form>
        <table class="uk-table" id="question_table">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>Topic</th>
        <th>Difficulty</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Question</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Strings</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Not</td>
        <td class="medium">Write a function named not_string that takes argument str and adds 'not' to the front of the given string, unless the string already begins with 'not' then return the string unchanged.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Conditionals</td>
        <td>Easy</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td class="easy">Write a function named hello_there that takes parameters a_hello and b_hello that returns true if both a and b are saying hello or if neither of them are. Print false otherwise.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Functions</td>
      <td>Easy</td>
      <td>sum</td>
      <td class="easy">Write a function named sum that takes arguments x,y and returns the sum of two numbers.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Loops</td>
      <td>Medium</td>
      <td>count</td>
      <td class="medium">Write a function named count that takes two arguments sequence and item that returns the number of times the item occurs in the list.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Functions</td>
      <td>Easy</td>
      <td>mult</td>
      <td class="easy">Write a function named mult that takes parameters a,b,c and returns the product of those three numbers.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Strings</td>
      <td>Hard</td>
      <td>appendMiddle</td>
      <td class="hard">Write a function named appendMiddle that takes arguments s1 and s2 and creates a new string by appending s2 in the middle of s1.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Strings</td>
      <td>Hard</td>
      <td>findAll</td>
      <td class="hard">Write a function named findAll that takes an input string as its argument and counts all lowercase,uppercase,digits,and special symbols.Then prints the counts.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Loops</td>
      <td>Hard</td>
      <td>digit_sum</td>
      <td class="hard">Write a function called digit_sum that takes a positive integer n as input and returns the sum of all that number's digits.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Loops</td>
      <td>Hard</td>
      <td>factorial</td>
      <td class="hard">Write a function named factorial that takes a non-negative integer x that can multiply all the integers from 1 through x.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm new to javascript, so this is what i've tried so far:

```
<script>
  function select(){
  var input = document.getElementById('dflag').value;
  var filter = input.value;
  table = document.getElementById("question_table");
  if dflag.value == 'Easy' {
    display.getElementsByClassName('easy');
  }
  else if dflag.value== 'Medium' {
    display.getElementsByClassName('medium');
  }
  else {
    display.getElementsByClassName('hard');
  }

}
</script>
```

I cannot use any libraries, so no jquery. Any ideas please?

Comment: S.O. isn't a site for helping with homework. It's for asking a community specific questions. What's your question here? If your question is "is there a better way to do this?" Then the answer is yes, but there are many different ways of achieving this, and your question doesn't specify how we should narrow down. In any case, you're asking for opinions, which isn't suitable for S.O.

Comment: you should mention what you've tried and what the errors you got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u should give value as  easy ,medium ,hard then filter with its value

```js
 function select(){
  var input = document.getElementById('dflag').value;
    document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(element=>{
      element.style.display = "table-row";
    })
 
    document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.'+input+')').forEach(element=>{
      element .style.display = "none";
    })

}
```

```html
<div class="search">

  <label for="dflag"> Difficulty: </label>
  <select id="dflag" name="dflag"onchange="select()">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="easy">Easy</option>
      <option value="medium">Medium</option>
      <option value="hard">Hard</option>

      </select>
</div>
<div class="search">
  <label for="tflag"> Topic: </label>
  <select id="tflag" name="tflag">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="A">Arrays</option>
        <option value="S">Strings</option>
        <option value="C">Conditionals</option>
        <option value="L">Loops</option>
       </select>
</div>`<button type="submit" onclick="select()"> Submit </button>`


<div class="input-group mb-3">
      <form>
        <table class="uk-table" id="question_table">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>Topic</th>
        <th>Difficulty</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Question</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="medium">
        <td>Strings</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Not</td>
        <td >Write a function named not_string that takes argument str and adds 'not' to the front of the given string, unless the string already begins with 'not' then return the string unchanged.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="easy">
        <td>Conditionals</td>
        <td>Easy</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td >Write a function named hello_there that takes parameters a_hello and b_hello that returns true if both a and b are saying hello or if neither of them are. Print false otherwise.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr  class="easy">
      <td>Functions</td>
      <td>Easy</td>
      <td>sum</td>
      <td>Write a function named sum that takes arguments x,y and returns the sum of two numbers.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="medium">
      <td>Loops</td>
      <td>Medium</td>
      <td>count</td>
      <td>Write a function named count that takes two arguments sequence and item that returns the number of times the item occurs in the list.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="easy">
      <td>Functions</td>
      <td>Easy</td>
      <td>mult</td>
      <td>Write a function named mult that takes parameters a,b,c and returns the product of those three numbers.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hard">
      <td>Strings</td>
      <td>Hard</td>
      <td>appendMiddle</td>
      <td>Write a function named appendMiddle that takes arguments s1 and s2 and creates a new string by appending s2 in the middle of s1.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hard">
      <td>Strings</td>
      <td>Hard</td>
      <td>findAll</td>
      <td>Write a function named findAll that takes an input string as its argument and counts all lowercase,uppercase,digits,and special symbols.Then prints the counts.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hard">
      <td>Loops</td>
      <td>Hard</td>
      <td>digit_sum</td>
      <td>Write a function called digit_sum that takes a positive integer n as input and returns the sum of all that number's digits.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hard">
      <td>Loops</td>
      <td>Hard</td>
      <td>factorial</td>
      <td>Write a function named factorial that takes a non-negative integer x that can multiply all the integers from 1 through x.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```